# Error on sharing the content to LinkedIn

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I have successfully integrated LinkedIn native application in my application using `LinkedIn mobile SDK`.

I am able to login successfully with my application but the problem is with sharing the content. While I successfully logged in , want to share my content to Linked in but it always give me error response

```
{
 "errorCode": 0,
 "message": "Access to posting shares denied",
 "requestId": "MBB3L0G1KZ",
 "status": 403,
 "timestamp": 1452172936679
}
```

though i have added all permission to LinkedIn[image]

I have made share function.

```
 void shareImageOnLinkedIn() {
    String shareJsonText = "{ \n" +
            "   \"comment\":\"" + "TalkingBookz" + "\"," +
            "   \"visibility\":{ " +
            "      \"code\":\"anyone\"" +
            "   }," +
            "   \"content\":{ " +
            "      \"title\":\"+audiobookinfo.title+\"," +
            "      \"description\":\"+audiobookinfo.description+\"," +
            "      \"submitted-url\":\"+audiobookinfo.sample_url+\"," +
            "      \"submitted-image-url\":\"+audiobookinfo.cover_url+\"" +
            "   }" +
            "}";

    // Call the APIHealper.getInstance method and pass the current context.
    APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    // call the apiHelper.postRequest with argument(Current context,url and content)
    apiHelper.postRequest(BookdetailActivity.this,
            shareUrl, shareJsonText, new ApiListener() {

                @Override
                public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {

                    Log.e("Response", apiResponse.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shared Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

                @Override
                public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {

                    Log.e("Response", error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Now I am calling this function after successfull login response. Here,

```
LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(this, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthSuccess() {
            Log.e("Access Token :", LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().toString());
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success" + LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getSession().getAccessToken().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            shareImageOnLinkedIn();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {

            Log.v("Error", error.toString());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed " + error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, true);
```

I have tried all the way to solve but i couldn't. So please give your feedback or suggestion. Advance help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have figured out what i have missed. My code was

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
}
```

So changed to

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.W_SHARE);
}
```

So now its working very fine !!

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your `LISessionManager`, you pass it a set of OAuth scopes that you want it to use for the connection.  In your sample code above, this happens via the `buildScope()` method that you did not include in your original question, so I can't really know for sure ... but I suspect that even though you have your LinkedIn app configured to request the `w_share` member permission, you are not doing the same in the `buildScope()` process, which will trump whatever values you set as defaults in your app's config.

Ensure your buildScope() method contains the static value for the `w_share` member permission, e.g.:

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.W_SHARE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. But actually yesterday i have solved my issue regarding this.