# Share with linkedin OAuth 2

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, retrofit2

I am trying to share posts to linkedin and logged in using OAuth 2 but i got this response

```
`{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Access to shares denied",
  "requestId": "0N4OYBHUMX",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1458564792498
}`
```

Am using `Retrofit 2` to make the connection and i posted this headers as linkedin [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) said.

```
@POST("people/~/shares")
Call<SilentShareLinkedInModel> SilentShareLinkedIn(@Query("oauth2_access_token") String accessToken,
                                                   @Query("format") String format,
                                                   @Header("Content-Type") String ContentType,
                                                   @Header("x-li-format") String xliformat);
```

this is the method call:

```
private void shareLinked() {
    String aboutTrip = searchWriteSomething.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user_info", 0);
    String token = prefs.getString("accessToken", "");
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    LinkedAPI api = retrofit.create(LinkedAPI.class);
    SilentShareLinkedInModel model =
            new SilentShareLinkedInModel(aboutTrip, new VisibilityModel("anyone"));
    Call<SilentShareLinkedInModel> response = api.SilentShareLinkedIn(token, "json","application/json","json");
    response.enqueue(new Callback<SilentShareLinkedInModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SilentShareLinkedInModel> call, Response<SilentShareLinkedInModel> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Posted to linked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.wtf("ShareLinked", response.raw().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SilentShareLinkedInModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "failed Post to linked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Also i used those permissions scopes in the login process

`r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20r_network%20w_share`

What's wrong in this code and why always show this message?

> Access to shares denied

Comment: Take a look at this similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656390/error-on-sharing-the-content-to-linkedin

Comment: He uses linkedin sdk with build scope w_share,I also add w_share in scope but with oauth2